# C adds a reference to array, not a value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

I am new to C and have never done anything with a non-OOP language.

I have an array of structs. It is global to the class and I parse a json with the results ending up in above mentioned array. I create an object (?) based on the struct that offers one property for every entry. **After adding the items, the array turned out to have the same value on all of the positions.**

I did remember C being tricky when it comes to values and pointers/references so I have made a little test to see whether the array actually only took the reference:

```
typedef struct  {
    char* name;
} ww_item ;

char nameW[40];

// iterating through json {
// strcpy(nameW, data);

    ww_item w = { nameW };

    ww_items [ position ] = w;

    strcpy(nameW, "d"); //replaces the "Hello" with "d" in all previous ww_items
```

Obviously it does, which explains why my array ends up being a repetition of the last element that has been added to it instead of listing all the different strings I have added to it.

I am unable to find any short information on this and unfortunately my deadline is too close to read through a whole C book now. I'm pretty sure that my assumptions so far are true but now I do not know what to search for/ to look for in order to solve this problem.

I'm okay with an ugly solution or workaround but at the moment I am just stuck with this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In C, arrays decay into pointers in many situations. They're never copied automatically.

Comment: You don't need to read a whole textbook, just the chapter on arrays.

Comment: Show the definition of `ww_item`. Its member must be a pointer, not an array. When you assign to it, you just get the address of the original array, not a copy.

Comment: You need to use `malloc()` to allocate new space for the array, then use `strcpy()` to copy the contents.

Comment: @Barmar I've edited the post to show how I declare the `nameW`. I have declared it outside of my loop. In the loop it will get overwritten by `strcpy` and eventually goes into `w`.

Comment: I asked for the definition of the `ww_item` structure.

Comment: When you write `{ nameW }` it's equivalen to `{ &nameW[0] }`. When you use an array as an r-value it gets turned into the address.

Comment: You can't use assignment to copy an array, it always turns into the address when you use it as the source of an assignment. This should be explained in any C textbook or tutorial. If you haven't been studying before the deadline, that's your own problem.

Comment: Boom it hit me when you asked me to show the structure. You guessed right. The struct had `char* name` instead of `char name[40]`. Now I am doing `strcpy(w.name, nameW)` and everything is working. Thank you so much. Write a short answer and I will tick (after getting out of bed tomorrow morning hahaha). Thank you

Comment: Make sure you are also allocating memory for the `w.name` before doing the copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `name` member from a pointer to an array.

```
typedef struct  {
    char name[40];
} ww_item ;
```

and then use `strcpy()`

```
strcpy(ww_items[position].name, w);
```

There's no need for the `w` variable.